# postgres 'WITH' clause with jooq

Tags: java, sql, common-table-expression, jooq, with-clause

Hell, I can't find a way to use the postgres 'WITH' clause with JOOQ.
Could you please let me know if it's supported by JOOQ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Common table expressions (the "`WITH` clause") are currently not supported in jOOQ. There is a pending feature request on the jOOQ road map for CTE's: [#454](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/454). As of jOOQ 3.0, there are currently no plans of actually supporting it, though.

(Your best option to push things a little bit is to discuss this topic on the [jOOQ user group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/jooq-user))