# jOOQ Dynamic WITH Clause

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, common-table-expression, jooq

I am unable to find documentation on how to dynamically construct WITH Clauses (i.e. Common Table Expressions / CTEs) in jOOQ. My use case is this :

- I need to nest dynamically created columns in order to produce new data from those dynamically created columns
- For example, I am creating a new field which is the non-null result from a full outer join. This field is ONLY available at the time of the query execution, so I need to store it within a WITH clause to reference it in other queries for additional calculations.
- Ideally, I would be able to request a WITH clause type query dynamically, and this dependency can be sorted out by placing this joined dataset in its own CTE to use in downstream references.

I am attempting to use the following, with no luck:

```java
    SelectQuery<Record> query =
        getQuery(
            dslContext,
            selectFields,
            fromClause,
            groupFields,
            conditionClause,
            orderFields,
            query.getOffset(),
            query.getLimit());

    // WORKS JUST FINE
    Supplier<Stream<Map<String, Object>>> results = () ->
        query
            .fetchStream()
            .map(Record::intoMap);

    // make a nested query here. static for now.
    // DOES NOT WORK
    Supplier<Stream<Map<String, Object>>> resultsWith =
        () ->
            DSL.with("s1")
                .as(query) // Shouldn't I be able to reference a SelectQuery here?
                .select()
                .from(table(name("s1")))
                .fetchStream()
                .map(Record::intoMap);
```

query.toString() looks something like this:

```sql
select 
  table1.field1,
  coalesce( 
    table1.id, 
    table2.id) as table1.id_table2.id, 
  count(*) as table2.field1.count, 
  sum(table2.field2) as table2.field2.sum
  from table1.table1 as table1
  full outer join table2.table2 as table2
  on table1.id = table2.id
  where table1.field2 < 3000.0
  group by 
  table1.id_table2.id,
  table1.field1
  order by table1.field1 asc
  limit 100
```

What I would like to do **at a minimum** is to reference the `coalesced` field above in additional downstream queries. Ideally I would not be limited at all in the manner or number of dynamic references I could make when constructing a WITH clause in jOOQ. In the end, I want to be able to dynamically create queries such as these, which show CTEs referencing CTEs too :

```sql
-- WITH Clause usage is preferrable
with
  myFirstSelection as (
    select
      (id + 100) as newfield
    from table1.table1 n
  ),
  mySecondSelection as (
    select
      (newField + 200) as newerField
    from myFirstSelection
  )
select
* 
from mySecondSelection
;

-- Inline queries, while not ideal, would be permissible
select 
* 
from (
  select
  (newField + 200) as newerField
  from (
    select
      (id + 100) as newField
    from table1.table1 n
  ) as myFirstSelection
) as mySecondSelection
;
```

Would that even be possible? Or am I limited to static tables and static selections?

---

## LINKS

#### stackoverflow

- ['WITH' Clause not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14456985/postgres-with-clause-with-jooq)
- [JOIN on a CTE in jOOQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44481307/jooq-query-to-join-on-with-clause)
- [Reference CTE in another CTE #1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59271846/jooq-error-relation-cte-does-not-exist)
  [Reference CTE in another CTE #2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59232161/how-to-re-use-one-cte-in-another-cte-in-jooq)

#### jOOQ Website

- [Building SQL : WITH Clause](https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.13/manual/sql-building/sql-statements/with-clause/)
- [v3.13 Manual : WITH Clause](https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.13/manual-single-page/#with-clause)
  [WithStep Javadocs](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/WithStep.html)

#### GitHub

- [Old CTETests repository which has been
  removed](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/blob/06574b9d4c1c88579bf0bd8ad376fc7a02158bd2/jOOQ-test/src/test/java/org/jooq/test/all/testcases/CTETests.java)
- [Issue 454 : Add CTE
  Support](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/454)
- [Issue 3174 : Add
  CTE Support w/ DML](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/3174)
- [Issue 3175 : Nested CTE](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/3175)
- [Issue 4474 : Form CTE from Plain
  SQL](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/4474)

#### jOOQ Google Group

- [How to handle names etc. for Common Table Expressions?](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/jooq-user/CTE|sort:date/jooq-user/7wPkNIfUviM/7bCmsUdeAwAJ)
- [Using arbitrary SQL string as a CTE in conjunction with the DSL](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/jooq-user/CTE|sort:date/jooq-user/I4gmUD7MvXo/dekaA_S9DwAJ)
- [WITH RECURSIVE CTE in Postgres](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/jooq-user/CTE|sort:date/jooq-user/vi3uGS8jajY/gQg87jEc7jgJ)
- [CTEs, recursive CTEs and JOOQ](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/jooq-user/CTE|sort:date/jooq-user/9Pk938yCp2o/b4M3Fx38Jg0J)
- [Recursive CTE](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/jooq-user/WITH$20Clause|sort:date/jooq-user/AT6IhghS9cg/vmD-IfInBQAJ)
- [Recursive CTE](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/jooq-user/WITH$20Clause$20CTE|sort:date/jooq-user/9Pk938yCp2o/q0XV2FIMExsJ)

Comment: Why doesn't it work?

Comment: I will create a new branch and get the stack trace soon

Comment: @LukasEder I rearranged the input payload for creating my query. This example is working properly now, actually. Thank you for reviewing. I have a follow-up question though -- is there an example in the documentation somewhere for using a loop to build the entire query, cte-by-cte? If you would prefer a new question on S.O., please let me know.

Comment: Glad it worked now. Did you find out what the cause was? It could be useful to answer your own question, in case someone stumbles upon this in the future... I'll be very happy to explain this step-by-step CTE creation in a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue turned out to be an issue with Jackson deserialization in a property in my JSON payload which gets turned into my query. I was getting a `NullPointerException` when one of the properties was getting converted into a part of the query class. With regards to `jOOQ`, this example works fine. As an addition, this is a testing query which sums the first field by referencing relative position in the result-set :

```java
    /* Output looks like this : 
    +-----------------+
    |sum_of_everything|
    +-----------------+
    |              100|
    +-----------------+
     */

    Supplier<Stream<Map<String, Object>>> resultsWith =
        () ->
            dslContext
                .with("s1")
                .as(query)
                .select(sum(field("1", Integer.class)).as("sum_of_everything"))
                .from(table(name("s1")))
                .fetchStream()
                .map(Record::intoMap);
```

This supplier can be returned as a response in a RESTful framework to stream results back to the requestor.